# style for tag `li`

Tags: html, css

I want put following check mark in side right tag `<li>`. How is it?

This check mark: [image]

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/HpVcy/

```
ul li{
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
background:url(http://img4up.com/up2/73089745861375946127.png) no-report;    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
ul li{
padding: 3px 15px 3px 10px;
background:url(http://img4up.com/up2/73089745861375946127.png) no-repeat right;    
}
```

Note: It's no-repeat, not no-report

Answer (score 2):

you can add
`li {
list-style-image: url("http://img4up.com/up2/73089745861375946127.png") 
}`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HpVcy/7/

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image

Answer (score 1):

`list-style-image` is what you are looking for:

```
ul li{
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  background:url(http://img4up.com/up2/73089745861375946127.png) no-report;    
  list-style-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5PA.png);
}
```

(you may want to delete the `background` url after adding the `list-style-image`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `no-repeat;` instead of `no-report;`

Answer (score 1):

you have no-report in your css, it should be no-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Change your background to:

```
background:url(http://img4up.com/up2/73089745861375946127.png) no-repeat right;    
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and increase the padding on the right a bit, e.g.:

```
ul{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 50px 50px 0 0;
}
ul li{
padding: 3px 20px 3px 10px;
background:url(http://img4up.com/up2/73089745861375946127.png) no-repeat right;    
}
```